# Creating a cloudFormation waitCondition with constant timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using **Two Custom Resources** in my **cloudFormation template.** Basically these Custom Resources are lambda functions which have custom code. I want to **start** the **creation** of **second lambda** after a **constant 3 minutes**.

I thought using the cloudFormation's **WaitCondition**  with **timeout property** to solve this. But it need a **WaitHandle** which has to receive success signals before the timeout. Once the signals are received, the WaitCondition turns to **Create-Complete.** But in my case, I cant make the custom function to send signal to wait handle. I need to have a constant 3 minute wait time after completion of **First Custom Resource.** Then, start the creation of **Second Custom Resource** after the **Create-Complete** of **WaitCondition.** Here is my code:

```
"SecondCustomResource": {
  "Type": "Custom::SecondCustomResource",
  "DependsOn" : "WaitCondition",
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["SecondCustomResourceFunction", "Arn"] }
  }
},


"SecondCustomResourceFunction": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Code": {
        "S3Bucket": { "Ref": "S3Bucket" },
        "S3Key": { "Ref": "S3Key" }
    },
    "Handler": { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [{ "Ref": "ModuleName" },".handler"] ] },
    "Runtime": "nodejs4.3",
    "Timeout": "30"
  }
},


"WaitCondition": {
  "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition",
  "DependsOn" : "FirstCustomResource",
  "Properties": {
    "Timeout": "180"
  }
},


"FirstCustomResource": {
  "Type": "Custom::FirstCustomResource",
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["FirstCustomResourceFunction", "Arn"] }
  }
},


"FirstCustomResourceFunction": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Code": {
        "S3Bucket": { "Ref": "S3Bucket" },
        "S3Key": { "Ref": "S3Key" }
    },
    "Handler": { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [{ "Ref": "ModuleName" },".handler"] ] },
    "Runtime": "nodejs4.3",
    "Timeout": "30"
  }
}
```

This does not seem to work. Any hack or work-around to have a constant WaitCondition ?

Comment: Do you have an instance in the stack that could provide the "sleep" then signal the handle?

Comment: No. I am deploying a kubernetes cluster in the custom function. Sending the success signal from Google cloud would be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

> > I just want a constant 3 minute wait time between my first and second custom resource. Is this possible ? <<

Probably.  I would think you want to try it by doing these two things.
1. Put a "sleep" function into the FirstCustomResourceFunction that sleeps for 3 minutes before signalling success.  See this, super important, look for "SUCCESS" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html

2. Have SecondCustomResourceFunction depend on FirstCustomResource.  That way it will not start until FirstCustomResource is complete (aka sleep and then success).

I think you can get rid of the WaitConditions then.

Be aware that "All calls made to AWS Lambda must complete execution within 300 seconds.".  (https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)  So, if your deployment grows by 60%, you're probably cooked.  (That's one of the reasons I was trying to steer you away from using Lambda as a wait state).  I really would try to find some better way.  In 15 years as DevOps, I've never arrived at "a constant value wait state" being a successful long term solution.

Comment: Interesting!! I thought this, but it is going to be expensive one, when I wait inside the Lambda for the cluster to change the state to Running. I understand your concern on the constant 3 minutes, I think I have to come up with some other solution.

Comment: Lambda limit is now 900 seconds (15 minutes)  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html